# Glsl skinning obstacle, who can jump that?

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl, skinning

I'm currently trying to set up a GPU skinning (with glsl) but it's not working the way I would :) Actually it's not working at all. My mesh disappear when I try this glsl code :

```
layout(location = 0) in vec3    vertexPos;
layout(location = 1) in vec2    vertexUv;
layout(location = 2) in vec3    vertexNor;
layout(location = 5) in ivec4   joints_influences;
layout(location = 6) in vec4    weights_influences;

uniform mat4    ViewProj, View, Proj, Model;
out vec3        vertexPosEye;
out vec3        vertexNorEye;

const int       MAX_INFLUENCES = 4;
const int       MAX_BONES = 50;
uniform mat4    animation_matrices[MAX_BONES];
uniform mat4    inv_bind_matrices[MAX_BONES];

void main()
{
    vertexPosEye = (View * Model * vec4(vertexPos, 1)).xyz;     // Position
    vertexNorEye = (View * Model * vec4(vertexNor, 0)).xyz;     // Normal matrix

    vec4 final_v = vec4(0, 0, 0, 0);

    for (int i = 0; i < MAX_INFLUENCES; i++)
    {
        vec4 v =        vec4(vertexPos, 1)
                    *   inv_bind_matrices[joints_influences[i]]
                    *   animation_matrices[joints_influences[i]]
                    *   weights_influences[i];

        final_v += v;
    }
    gl_Position =  ViewProj * Model * final_v;
}
```

when I try this :

```
gl_Position =  ViewProj * Model * vertexPos;
```

My mesh is back :) but no animations anymore of course...

Here's my application (c++) code when I set VBO attributes :

```
// Vertex position
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer[0]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[0]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.pos.size() * sizeof(bVector3), &vertices.pos[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Ibid for uv, normals, tangents and bitangents.

// Skinning : joints index
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer[5]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[5]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.joints.size() * sizeof(SkinningJoints), &vertices.joints[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Skinning : weights
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer[6]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[6]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.weights.size() * sizeof(SkinningWeights), &vertices.weights[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);

// Indices
glGenBuffers(1, &buffer[7]);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer[7]);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vertices.indices.size() * sizeof(bUshort), &vertices.indices[0], GL_STATIC_DRAW);
```

In the main loop :

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m->GetBuffer(0));
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(for uv, normals, tangents and bitangents)...

glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m->GetBuffer(5));
glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glEnableVertexAttribArray(6);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m->GetBuffer(6));
glVertexAttribPointer(6, 4, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));

glBindBuffer(GL_ELEMENT_ARRAY_BUFFER, m->GetBuffer(7));
glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, m->vertices.indices.size(), GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

Here is my RenderingVertices struct (after Barr's recomendations):

```
struct RenderingVertices
{
    // std::vector<Vec3>
    vVec3                       pos, nor, tang, btan;
    vVec2                       uv;
    vUshort                     indices;

    vector<SkinningJoints>      joints;
    vector<SkinningWeights>     weights;
};
```

And here is my SkinningJoints struct :

```
struct SkinningJoints
{
    int         j[MAX_BONES_PER_VERT];

    SkinningJoints(Vertex::Weights weights[MAX_BONES_PER_VERT])
    {
        for (bUint i = 0; i < MAX_BONES_PER_VERT; i++)
            j[i] = weights[i].jid;
    }
};
```

My SkinningWeights struct is almost the same, with an array of float instead of int.

Now when I try to debug the joints index, weights values and final vertex as colors, here is what I get :

```
// Shader
color_debug = joints_influences;
```

http://www.images-host.fr/view.php?img=00021800pop.jpg

```
color_debug = weights_influences;
```

http://www.images-host.fr/view.php?img=00021800pop2.jpg

Another interesting thing, when I try this :

```
vec4 pop = vec4(vertexPos, 1) * animation_matrices[1] * inv_bind_matrices[1] * 1.0;
gl_Position =  ViewProj * Model * pop;
```

My all mesh is actually rotating, which means that my uniform animation_matrices is good.

Anyone can see what i'm doing wrong here ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you try debugging your skinning attributes? Output the vertex weight as colors so that you can confirm you have meaningful values? If everything is black you'll know where to look.

From a quick glance at your RenderingVertices I can spot a first problem. You are passing a Vector of pointers to GL which I don't think is what you want to do.

Most of the time you will limit skinning influences to 4 joint/weight pairs per vertex. So you can get away with a simple array (ie. SkinningJoints joints[4];).

Comment: Here is what I get when I put "layout(location = 6) in vec4    weights_influences;" as color.

http://www.images-host.fr/view.php?img=17021756pop.jpg

Answer (score 4):

I finally got it working. For those who may be interested, here is what I was doing wrong :

When I send joints indices array to Glsl, instead of doing this:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m->GetBuffer(5));
glVertexAttribPointer(5, 4, GL_INT, GL_FALSE, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

I needed to do this:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(5);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, m->GetBuffer(5));
glVertexAttribIPointer(5, 4, GL_INT, 0, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
```

You have to look closely to find the difference. Instead of calling glVertexAttribPointer(), I needed to call glVertexAttribIPointer() because joints indices are `int`.

Hope this will help someone someday.